# Why laravel assertions are not called from closure?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My code is:

```
public function testOne()
{
    $mail = ['subject' => 'My subject'];

    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    $mock = Mockery::mock(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::getSwiftMailer());
    $this->app['mailer']->setSwiftMailer($mock);
    $msg = $mock->shouldReceive('send')->once()->andReturnUsing(function($msg) {
        echo $msg->getSubject();
        $this->assertEquals($mail['subject'], $msg->getSubject());
    });
    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
}
```

I get output:

```
PHPUnit 4.8.24 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

My subject

Time: 852 ms, Memory: 26.00Mb

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```

I see from output:

```
echo $msg->getSubject();
```

that I get good subject but nothing is asserted, why?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
public function testOne()
{
    $mail = ['subject' => 'My subject'];

    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    $mock = Mockery::mock(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::getSwiftMailer());
    $this->app['mailer']->setSwiftMailer($mock);
    $obj = $this;
    $msg = $mock->shouldReceive('send')->once()->andReturnUsing(function($msg) use ($obj, $mail) {
        echo $msg->getSubject();
        $obj->assertEquals($mail['subject'], $msg->getSubject());
    });
    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
}
```

Inside your `closure` it's an instance of `Closure` so it will not get `$this` from there for that you have to assign to another variable & use it.

> **`But you can rewrite your tests like this`**

```
public function testOne()
{
    $mail = ['subject' => 'My subject'];

    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    $mock = Mockery::mock(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::getSwiftMailer());
    $this->app['mailer']->setSwiftMailer($mock);
    $message = null;
    $mock->shouldReceive('send')->once()->andReturnUsing(function($msg) use ($message) {
        $message = $msg->getSubject();
    });
    $this->assertEquals($mail['subject'], $message);
    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
}
```

Comment: There is strange error with your solution, if there is false assertion inside closure laravel print like it is true....and more if any error occurs inside closure is not printed...

Comment: You didn't use `$mail` in closure also you can rewrite your tests. Check my answer now @fico7489

Comment: Your second snippet returns "class Mockery\CompositeExpectation" object not string.